# Elasticsearch 2 + PHP scroll flow issue

Tags: php, elasticsearch, scroll

Hi can somebody tell me please how to execute scroll on Elasticsearch 2 via PHP Ruflin\Elastica library?
According [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/search-request-scroll.html) for ES2 first scroll request should lead to specific index while next requests are called without index with only scroll_id parameter.
So I wrote this code:

```
/** @var Elastica\Client $elastic */
$elastic = $container->getService( 'elastica' );

// This first call works fine. I get the scroll_id.
$elasticScrollData = $elastic->getIndex( 'event' )->request( '_search?scroll=5m', 'GET', ['size' => 500, 'sort' => ['_doc']] )->getData();

$countAll = $elasticScrollData['hits']['total'];

saveToMongo( $elasticScrollData, $countAll, $elastic );


function saveToMongo( $scrollData, $countAll, \Elastica\Client $elastic )
{
    $documents = [];
    foreach ( $scrollData['hits']['hits'] as $item )
    {
        $doc = [];
        $doc['ico'] = (array)$item['_source']['ico'];
        ...         

        $documents[] = $doc;
    }

    try
    {
        saveDataToDb( $documents );
    }
    catch( \Exception $e )
    {
        echo '+++ insert exception: ' . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    }

    // Here is the problem. It throws me an exception: No enabled connection
    $scrollData = $elastic->request( '_search/scroll', 'GET', ['scroll' => '5m', 'scroll_id' => $scrollData['_scroll_id']] )->getData();

    saveToMongo( $scrollData, $countAll, $offset, $elastic, $mongoCollection );
}
```

What is wrong with the second call to Elasticsearch? Why it throws error: No enabled connection? Hope somebody knows cause I really dont.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Elastica\Client` use a round-robin connection pool by default to resolve connectivity issue, If all connections are gone, It throw `ClientException` with message `No enabled connection`[1](https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica/blob/3.2.3/lib/Elastica/Connection/Strategy/Simple.php).

Check your network connectivity between PHP script and Elasticsearch and review your configuration for Elasticsearch.

Comment: Yes thats it. Thanks.